# How many different hauls can he take?

Tags: probability, combinations

A pirate finds a treasure chest containing 7 diamonds, 9 pearls, and 216 doubloons. Unfortunately, he can only carry 50 objects away with him. How many different hauls can he take?

I know that I should just consider about diamonds and pearls, because total number of diamonds and pearls is 16, that means I should choose at least 34 doubloons. But I do not know how to choose diamonds and pearls.

So, for (m,n) is 8*10 because I can choose 0 diamonds and o pearls.

Comment: Welcome! Your question is getting downvoted because you don't show us any effort or express thoughts you have on the problem. Please show us some work, otherwise people may think you want us to just do your HW for you.

Comment: okay, I will show my work.

Comment: OK, thanks!  And yes, that first observation is good: pick some number of diamonds and pearls, and fill up the rest with doubloons. So, another way of putting this is: let's say we pick $m$ diamonds, and $n$ pearls ... then $(m,n)$ represents a haul, since again: with $m$ and $n$ fixed, we can just fill up the rest with doubloons. So the question becomes: what are all possible pairs $(m,n)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 8 different options to choose diamonds (from 0 to 7): for example, you can take all the diamonds or can take none of them. Similarly with pearls - 10 options. The empty space is filled with doubloons.

For any pair of diamond-pearl there is only one possible number of doubloons. For example, if you take $7$ diamonds and $2$ pearls, there will be $50-(7+2)=41$ doubloons.

In this way, the number of samples depends on the number of selected pearls and diamonds.

As I said earlier, $8$ different options to choose diamonds and $10$ to choose perls. The number of samples is $8 \cdot 10=80$.

Comment: thank you for helping me